# Adding Google Analytics tracking to python without messing it up

Tags: python, html

So I have my google analytics tracking code snippet, which normally works fine, but I'm trying to have that code appear in a webpage generated by my python program.  For the other html, i.e. body and content and forms and whatnot, I can just paste the code into my python script and it will display normally, but when I try to input my google code it throws a syntax error.  I think I need to tell Python not to try and execute the HTML as python code, and escape it somehow, but I don't know how.  Any tips?

Comment: This needs more context, normally with Python you would run a server and have it computer html files, either directly or via a templating  service like jinja. If you are doing this directly you should just include it to the end of your file while making sure you escape things correctly.

Comment: I'm sort of wondering how I would escape things correctly.

Comment: You could use triple quotes.